# How to force vim to edit a file which is open in a gVim session?

Tags: ssh, vim, gvim

I would like to edit a file in an SSH session on a server. That file is on a Network File System. I was editing it while sitting at a workstation in my office and I left a gVim session running with the file open when I left.

Now when I try to open that file in the SSH session:

```
$ vim file.name
File is being edited by GVIM
```

and it leaves me back on the prompt.

I don't have access to the workstation with the GVIM session from my home machine. Hence, I cannot `killall gvim` and start editing the file.

I'd expect this to be a fairly standard problem, but googling does not give me any obvious answers, which is making me suspicious that there is an obvious solution which I am missing.

Could anyone please tell me what it is?

Comment: There is `.<filename>.swp` file next to the `<filename>`. You might try to delete that file.

Comment: @Jakuje That did not allow me to open the file. However, I only get this error while inside a tmux session. If I reconnect the the machine and try vim from the console, it allows me to edit the file with a warning that it is being edited elsewhere. Curioser and curioser.

Comment: Do you have `packadd editexisting` in your .vimrc?